# parsing a text file into groups using Scala

Tags: parsing, scala

I have a CSV file that is really a set of many CSV files in one. Something like this:

```
"First Part"
"Some", "data", "in", "here"
"More", "stuff", "over", "here"

"Another Part"
"This", "section", "is", "not", "the", "same", "as", "the", "first"
"blah", "blah", "blah", "blah", "blah", "blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"

"Yet another section"
"And", "this", "is", "yet", "another"
"blah", "blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"
```

I'd like to break it into separate components. Given I know the header for each section, it'd be nice if I could do some kind of `groupBy` or something where I pass in a set of regexp's representing header patterns and return a `Seq[Seq[String]]` or something similar.

Comment: There could be many factors to consider. Do you need to process large files or can you load everything into memory? Do you need to handle escaped CSV characters? Do you care about performance or do you need something simple?

Comment: it's a small file... 100K max, so I was going to put everything into memory

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
val groups = List("\"First Part\"", "\"Another Part\"", "\"Yet another section\"")
val accumulator = List[List[String]]()
val result = input.split("\n").foldLeft(accumulator)((acc,e) => {
  if (groups.contains(e)) {
    // Make new group when we encounter a string matching one of the groups
    Nil :: acc
  } else {
    // Grab current group and modify it
    val newHead = e :: acc.head 
    newHead :: acc.tail 
  }
})
```

Each list in `result` now represent a group. If you want to use regex to find your matches then just replace the `groups.contains(e)` with a match test. There are some subtleties here that might deserve a mention:

- The algorithm will fail if the input does not start with a heading
- If a heading is present several times each time it is present will generate a new group
- Groups will contain the lines in the input in reverse.
- Empty lines will also be included in the result.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT this is similar to the other solution that was posted at the same time. A similar thing for the sections headings could be done instead of my quick hack of size==1. This solution has the added benefit of including the secion name so ordering doesn't matter.

```
val file: List[String] = """

heading
1,2,3
4,5

heading2
5,6
""".split("\n").toList
val splitFile = file
  .map(_.split(",").toList)
  .filterNot(_ == List(""))
  .foldLeft(List[(String, List[List[String]])]()){
    case (h::t,l) => {if(l.size==1) (l(0),List()):: h :: t else (h._1, l :: h._2) :: t}; 
    case (Nil, l)=> if(l.size==1) List((l(0),List())) else List() }
  .reverse
```

produces

```
 splitFile: List[(String, List[List[String]])] = List((heading,List(List(4, 5), List(1, 2, 3))), (heading2,List(List(5, 6))))
```